# Default values for a checkbox question

Tags: commcare

Looking to set default values for a checkbox question (want the user to see most of them selected). How should the choices be loaded into the default value box? I've tried comma and space separated lists of the values but am getting the following error message when I try to load the form "Encountered an error while processing the application. Please submit a ticket if you continue to see this."

Answer (score 1):

It should be entered as a space separated list of option ids.  Example:  "option_1 option_2 option_4"